# Date Header missing in WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, http

I am setting up a WCF service using SOAP over Http that uses custom authentication. I have an `IClientMessageInspector` implementation that should set both the authorisation string in the http header of the message, along with the date. Oddly, the authorization header gets set correctly, but examining the request server-side shows no date header has been set.

The relevant code is:

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
    var httpRequestMessage = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)request.Properties["httpRequest"];

    httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Date, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString());

    var authorisationValue = _userName + ":" + GenerateAuthorisationString();
    httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, authorisationValue);

    return null;
}
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong, or is there an alternative way to add the date header?

Comment: First question - have you configured `endpointBehaviors` properly like in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.beforesendrequest(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Yep, as I said, the authorization header that is being set here is being set, and the messageinspector is being called, it's just the date header that is not being set.